# Altering the Curve of a WebAudio WaveShaper Node While Playing

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm making a drum machine/sampler and I want the user to be able to control the amount of distortion on the output using a slider. I've made a WaveShaper node, connected it up appropriately, set the curve using an equation found on this site, all of that works ok.

Then I want a range input to call a function on the change event to reset the curve to provide more or less distortion according to the new value of the input.

Here's what I have:

```
// Distortion:
bussDistortion = audioContext.createWaveShaper();
bussDistortion.curve = makeDistortionCurve(0);
bussDistortion.connect(audioContext.destination);
// Slider:
distortionAmountSlider = document.querySelector('#distortion_amount');
// Event listener:
distortionAmountSlider.addEventListener('change', changeDistortionAmount, false);

// Update function:
function changeDistortionAmount() {
    bussDistortion.curve = makeDistortionCurve(distortionAmountSlider.value);
}

function makeDistortionCurve( amount ) {
    var k = typeof amount === 'number' ? amount : 50,
        n_samples = 44100,
        curve = new Float32Array(n_samples),
        i = 0,
        x;
    for ( ; i < n_samples; ++i ) {
        x = i * 2 / n_samples - 1;
        curve[i] = ( Math.PI + k ) * x * (1/6) / ( Math.PI + k * Math.abs(x) );
    }
    return curve;
}
```

What seems to be happening is that the first change of the slider causes the distortion curve to change to something, but after that further changes have no effect. Can anyone explain what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is where it goes wrong:

```
var k = typeof amount === 'number' ? amount : 50
```

The slider's value is a string, not a number, which would explain why it works the first time (it evaluates to 50). So if you do

```
makeDistortionCurve(parseInt(distortionAmountSlider.value, 10));
```

you should be good to go! (Or use parseFloat if you need a float..)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly it. I've never used the ternary operator before, I should've looked it up before copying the code :)